# Unexpected attribute 'indexes' error while following GAE tutorial

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, yaml

I am following google app engine getting started tutorials. I am at this point; https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/templates

I have tried to follow it to the point, but when I started my application from google app engine launcher, I see this in the logs;

```
---- a long traceback, followed by ---- 
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\yaml_listener.py", line 177, in _HandleEvents
    raise yaml_errors.EventError(e, event_object)
google.appengine.api.yaml_errors.EventError: Unexpected attribute 'indexes' for object of type AppInfoExternal.
  in "C:\Users\muhammed\Desktop\guestbook\app.yaml", line 18, column 1
2013-09-12 13:01:26 (Process exited with code 1)
```

Here is how my `app.yaml` file looks like;

```
application: your-app-id
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: guestbook.application

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: latest
- name: jinja2
  version: latest

indexes:
- kind: Greeting
  ancestor: yes
  properties:
  - name: date
    direction: desc
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tutorial doesn't tell you to put indexes into app.yaml. They go in a separate file, index.yaml. But you usually don't have to bother, as the dev server will create them for you when you run your code locally.

Comment: Thanks. I must have missed it.